# OpenCV predict() vs detectMultiScale()

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

I'm working on doing some Face, Gender, and Age detection using OpenCV. I have a bunch of images I use to train the models, Essentally I currently have the following:

```
Ptr<cv::face::FaceRecognizer> model = cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer::create(9, 9);
std::vector<int> labels;
std::vector<std::string> imageFileNames;

for (int currImageIndex = 0; currImageIndex < imageFileNames.size(); currImageIndex++)
{
    cv::Mat currMatrix;
    std::string currentFileName = imageFileNames[currImageIndex];
    std::string gender;
    int currID = -1;

    //Save the image and the corresponding ID to the list(s).
    currMatrix = imread(currentFileName , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (currMatrix.data != NULL)
    {
        images.push_back(currMatrix);
        labels.push_back(currID);
    }
}

model->train(images, labels);
model->write("C:\\temp.xml");
```

Then using the `temp.xml` heuristic, I predict the geneder like so:

```
gendermodel->predict(currMat, predictedLabel, conf);
```

However, I came across [this implementation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d3a/facedetect_8cpp-example.html#a25) using `detectMultiScale()` and a `"Cascade Classifier"`. What is the diffrence? Is there a performance advantage to using a `Cascade Classifier` vs the way I am currently doing it? Does `detectMultiScale()` work better then `predict()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#aaf8181cb63968136476ec4204ffca498) function is used for object **detection**. It returns a variable of type `std::vector<cv::Rect>` which contains bounding rectangles of detected objects.

[`FaceRecognizer::predict`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#ab0d593e53ebd9a0f350c989fcac7f251) function is used for object **classification**. It returns the class label of input image and the confidence with which the object is predicted.

Comment: Is it possible to use detectMultiScale to do some type of gender detection or is FaceRecognizer::predict() always used for classification?

Comment: @Katianie... Gender prediction is a classification problem so `FaceRecognizer::predict` is better suited for it. It may be achieved through `detectMultiScale` but that would be quite cumbersome and might not be accurate enough.